# Bazel Python Dependency Error - An error occurred during the fetch of repository python_external_deps

Tags: pip, bazel

A repo I am working with uses Bazel and I am running into following error with one of the Bazel commands that verifies that my set up is good.

```
repo %  bazel query infra/...

Loading: 0 packages loaded
INFO: Repository python_external_deps instantiated at:
  no stack (--record_rule_instantiation_callstack not enabled)
Repository rule pip_repository defined at:
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_septerr/2bcb6e5a56cd66d1868dc15259a19a8b/external/rules_python_external/defs.bzl:46:33: in <toplevel>
DEBUG: Rule 'rules_python_external' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments shallow_since = "1587525369 +1000"
DEBUG: Repository rules_python_external instantiated at:
  no stack (--record_rule_instantiation_callstack not enabled)
Repository rule git_repository defined at:
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_septerr/2bcb6e5a56cd66d1868dc15259a19a8b/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl:195:33: in <toplevel>
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'python_external_deps':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_septerr/2bcb6e5a56cd66d1868dc15259a19a8b/external/rules_python_external/defs.bzl", line 41, column 13, in _pip_repository_impl
        fail("rules_python_external failed: %s (%s)" % (result.stdout, result.stderr))
Error in fail: rules_python_external failed:  (  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /private/var/tmp/_bazel_septerr/2bcb6e5a56cd66d1868dc15259a19a8b/external/pypi__pip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/9j/xp6km4954fz256491861l2qr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-2niyw4p8/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.cbhq.net --extra-index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple/ -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (9 lines):
  Looking in indexes: https://pypi.cbhq.net, https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/44/a6/7fb6e8b3f4a6051e72e4e2218889351f0ee484b9ee17e995f5ccff780300/setuptools-50.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/00/3df031b3ecd5444d572141321537080b40c1c25e1caa3d86cdd12e5e919c/wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel
  ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/3.7'
  Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
  
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /private/var/tmp/_bazel_septerr/2bcb6e5a56cd66d1868dc15259a19a8b/external/pypi__pip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/9j/xp6km4954fz256491861l2qr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-2niyw4p8/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.cbhq.net --extra-index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple/ -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_septerr/2bcb6e5a56cd66d1868dc15259a19a8b/external/rules_python_external/extract_wheels/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    extract_wheels.main()
  File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_septerr/2bcb6e5a56cd66d1868dc15259a19a8b/external/rules_python_external/extract_wheels/__init__.py", line 70, in main
    [sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "wheel", "-r", args.requirements]
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 487, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', 'wheel', '-r', '/Users/septerr/src/sgupta/repo/requirements.txt.external']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
)
DEBUG: Rule 'c_rules_ruby' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments shallow_since = "1595625326 -0700"
DEBUG: Repository c_rules_ruby instantiated at:
  no stack (--record_rule_instantiation_callstack not enabled)
Repository rule git_repository defined at:
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_septerr/2bcb6e5a56cd66d1868dc15259a19a8b/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl:195:33: in <toplevel>
DEBUG: Rule 'com_github_atlassian_bazel_tools' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments shallow_since = "1586491416 +1000"
DEBUG: Repository com_github_atlassian_bazel_tools instantiated at:
  no stack (--record_rule_instantiation_callstack not enabled)
Repository rule git_repository defined at:
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_septerr/2bcb6e5a56cd66d1868dc15259a19a8b/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl:195:33: in <toplevel>
ERROR: no such package '@python_external_deps//': rules_python_external failed:  (  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /private/var/tmp/_bazel_septerr/2bcb6e5a56cd66d1868dc15259a19a8b/external/pypi__pip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/9j/xp6km4954fz256491861l2qr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-2niyw4p8/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.cbhq.net --extra-index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple/ -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (9 lines):
  Looking in indexes: https://pypi.cbhq.net, https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/44/a6/7fb6e8b3f4a6051e72e4e2218889351f0ee484b9ee17e995f5ccff780300/setuptools-50.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/00/3df031b3ecd5444d572141321537080b40c1c25e1caa3d86cdd12e5e919c/wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel
  ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/3.7'
  Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
  
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /private/var/tmp/_bazel_septerr/2bcb6e5a56cd66d1868dc15259a19a8b/external/pypi__pip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/9j/xp6km4954fz256491861l2qr0000gn/T/pip-build-env-2niyw4p8/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.cbhq.net --extra-index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple/ -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_septerr/2bcb6e5a56cd66d1868dc15259a19a8b/external/rules_python_external/extract_wheels/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    extract_wheels.main()
  File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_septerr/2bcb6e5a56cd66d1868dc15259a19a8b/external/rules_python_external/extract_wheels/__init__.py", line 70, in main
    [sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "wheel", "-r", args.requirements]
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 487, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', 'wheel', '-r', '/Users/septerr/src/sgupta/repo/requirements.txt.external']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
)
Loading: 0 packages loaded
    currently loading: infra/loadtesting/locust ... (3 packages)
```

The WORKSPACE file has following Python related statements:

```
###
# Python
###

load("@rules_python//python:repositories.bzl", "py_repositories")

py_repositories()

# Only needed if using the packaging rules.
load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "pip_repositories")

pip_repositories()

load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "pip3_import")

# Create a central repo that knows about the dependencies needed for
# requirements.txt.
pip3_import(
    name = "python_deps",
    requirements = "//:requirements.txt",
)

# Load the central repo's install function from its `//:requirements.bzl` file,
# and call it.
load("@python_deps//:requirements.bzl", "pip_install")

pip_install()

# With transitive dependencies in requirements.txt
# See example of use in //data/pkg.bzl
load("@rules_python_external//:repositories.bzl", "rules_python_external_dependencies")

rules_python_external_dependencies()

load("@rules_python_external//:defs.bzl", pip_install_external = "pip_install")

pip_install_external(
    name = "python_external_deps",
    requirements = "//:requirements.txt.external",
)
```

Comment: That is indeed weird. IIRC these `pip` rules are somewhat evil, because they (as repo rules do) sidestep bazel and do stuff (non-hermetically) on host (so also your python toolchain used in bazel may not actually match)... but that aside, with `--prefix ...` that is where requested stuff should be installed and not under `/Library/Python/3.7` that I presume to be system wide location on your platform / distro (apparently MacOS / Darwin). Still the question is why that `pip`; run like that; does this. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get past this issue by simply changing permissions for the /Library/Python directory.

```
sudo chown -R <username> /Library/Python
```